# JSF h:message or p:message does not work

Tags: validation, jsf

My application runs in glassfish. I do not see any h:message or h:messages (or, the primefaces messages)... Is there any configuration, I have to specify either in web.xml or faces-config.xml ?
Currently I have no way to see if any validation fails, even, required="true" with requiredMessages="Some Value" does not work..

Comment: Could you add some code? As you use primefaces, I assume that you are on jsf 2.0.

Comment: Can you check your log? Does it display "FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed" ?

Comment: @Matt, here is some example,   <p:messages />
          <p:growl />
          <p:commandButton value="Update" update="contentform:grid"
           actionListener="#{userPageBacking.updateUser}"
           oncomplete="dlg.show()"  />

Comment: @radkrish, it's the latest version 3 and no I do not see them in the log file

Comment: @user644745, i am not sure but i doubt whether <p:messages/> and <p:growl/> can be used together. Try with anyone of them and see whether it works or not.

Answer (score 3):

**JSF**

growl -> id="growl"

commandButton -> update="growl"

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="false" sticky="true" />  

            <p:commandButton value="Update" update="growl" actionListener="#{userPageBacking.updateUser}"/> 
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Backing Bean

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author ezehrt
 */
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UserPageBacking {

    public void updateUser() {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (fc.isValidationFailed()) {
            return;
        }


        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("fehlermeldung", "fehlermeldung");

        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);

        fc.addMessage("fehlermeldung", msg);

        fc.renderResponse();
    }
}
```

Comment: @edze thanks. problem is, it's not even hitting updateUser in #{userPageBacking.updateUser}  .. the bean is in viewScoped and I am not able to figure out why... I changed actionListener to action, but still it's not going inside the function updateUser. I changed the scope of the backing bean from viewScoped to requestScoped, but that also did not help. Also I changed the updateuser to some junk value and it did not throw any error... It should say that function/property not found..

Comment: I try it with @ViewScoped an it works fine. Do you use <h:form> ? Please post your code.

Comment: I tried ViewScoped, not working for me.. funniest part is, all my codebase is using this kind of actionListener call, but this one does not work.. also I have another commandButton, that works in the same page. If you know of any debugging technique please let me know.

Comment: I just see one warning, "Unable to find component with ID bankLoc in view."... I see "bankLoc" very much present... <p:inputText id="bankloc"
            value="#{userPageBacking.user.wudAccountDetail.wadBankLocation}" />
           <h:message for="bankLoc" showDetail="true" />

Comment: :-) Thanks. But in-spite of that it does not seem to work.. I was getting one more message in the log, is it something to do with glassfish ? ---- "Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context  because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called"